# Python: I'm not sure why my discord bot code is giving this error

Tags: python

I am trying to use mega.py to make a discord bot that will search your files on mega.nz, but is giving me some error and I have no clue what it means. The command would be >find (whatever you want to get in your MEGA archive, in my case, mp3 files), and I want the bot to send the MEGA link to the requested file in the Discord channel. This is my first project in python and I hope I can get past this error.

This is the error.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'member_descriptor' and 'str'
```

And this is the current code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from mega import Mega

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd)
    print('it worked?')

@client.event
async def on_message(find):
    mega = Mega()
    song = discord.Message.content
    m = mega.login("email", "password")
    file = m.find(song + '.mp3')
    link = m.get_link(file)
    if file:
        await ctx.send(link)
   

client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the discord API for python correctly `async def on_message`, takes an input which is the message. In this line:

`song = discord.Message.content`

You set song to something relative to the discord library, when you really should do:

`song = find.content`

which is a string.

Comment: Just tried that, and it got rid of my original error, but now its giving me a new one. `File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py", line 382, in get_link
    file = file[1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I believe that is a problem with how you are accessing the mega library. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with it. Did you post the whole error message? If there is more I may be able to help debug it.

Comment: There's the whole error. `Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\python projects\leakerbot.py", line 20, in on_message
    link = m.get_link(file)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py", line 382, in get_link
    file = file[1]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Perhaps you should check if the file exists?

Comment: The error indicates that 'file' is undefined (None type).

Comment: i'm 100% sure that every file i tried searching for with the bot exists inside my MEGA files

Comment: Perhaps try printing `song + '.mp3'`. Maybe the content includes the prefix (`>`) in which case you would have to remove it.